# Ajax/jQuery/PHP Set Cookies with Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have a login script that worked last night, made no modifications since then.

Before everyone downvotes, I have already read 10+ similar questions, but they didn't help me out.

I have a login page, with a user and pass field, when users submit, a jQuery event happens where it gets posted to a URL, and that PHP script then checks for the users existence and sets cookies if they do exist.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$.post('http://*******/login/', {user: $('.login-form input[name=username]').val(), pass: md5($('.login-form input[name=password]').val())}, function(data) {
    if(data.status == 'success') {  
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = '/dashboard.php';
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        alert('No valid user found');
    }
});
```

On the other end of this jQuery, is the PHP, which uses a basic API that I have built:

```
<?
require_once('../../classes/api.php');

$api = new API;

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if(strlen($password) != 32) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
    die();
}

$dbCon = $api->db("***");
$checkUser = $api->login($dbCon, "users", $username, $password);

if($checkUser == false) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
} else {
    $company = $api->getCompany($dbCon, "companies", $checkUser['company_id']);
    setcookie('first_name', $checkUser['first_name'], 0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
    setcookie('last_name', $checkUser['last_name'], 0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
    setcookie('company_id', $checkUser['company_id'], 0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
    setcookie('agency_account', $company['agency_account'], 0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
    setcookie('advertiser_id', $company['advertiser_id'], 0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
}

?>
```

When I check the Chrome DevTools network section for the post, it says:

```
Set-Cookie:first_name=first; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
Set-Cookie:last_name=last; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
Set-Cookie:company_id=1; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
Set-Cookie:agency_account=true; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
Set-Cookie:advertiser_id=12; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
```

But no new cookies are made. What could be causing this now? Like I said, it was working last night, but not today.

I am willing to add and edit the question and my code as needed.

Comment: why not just use one cookie?

Comment: I use different information for different things, and this is just what we require right now, and on top of that, some of the cookies will be much larger, and I don't want to accidentally loose data due to cookie size.

Comment: Aren't cookies only accessible client-side if they were there when the page loaded? So if you have index.php, and then you send an ajax that creates cookies, will index.php have access to them without refreshing? Probably not, although I've not tried it.

Comment: But that is the weird thing, it was working last night, which is why I am confused... Cookies are client side, so in theory, this shouldn't work anyway (? not 100% sure though), but it did, so I went with it, and now it isn't working.

Comment: Did you try reverting to the last known working version to see if it really worked?

Comment: Yes, I have, it didn't work anymore though, I wish I caught video or something of it happening so I could prove it, I am going nuts!